# How to process a sequence of multiple temporary files in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, temporary-files

I want to go through the following steps:

1) tempfileA  (Note: this is a blob downloaded from Google Cloud Storage)

2) tempfileB = function(tempfileA)

3) tempfileC = function(tempfileB)

This should be pretty straightforward, however, I am not sure about what's the best way to access different temporary files created in sequence based on the previous one.

So far I have found the example below from [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html), but the `Temporaryfile` is closed at the exit of the `with` clause, so it should not be possible to access the temp file in the next step.

```
# create a temporary file using a context manager
with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as fp:
     fp.write(b'Hello world!')
     fp.seek(0)
     fp.read()
```

Could you please suggest what would be a good way to achieve what described above? Please note that at each step a method from an external library is called to process the current temp file and the result should be the next temp file.

Answer (score 7):

You can open multiple files in the same `with` block.

```
with TemporaryFile() as fp0, TemporaryFile() as fp1, TemporaryFile() as fp2:
    fp0.write(b'foo')
    fp0.seek(0)
    fp1.write(fp0.read())
    ...
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [`TemporaryDirectory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory) and manually create files in there. For example:

```
import os
import tempfile

def process_file(f_name):
    with open(f_name) as fh:
        return fh.read().replace('foo', 'bar')

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as td:
    f_names = [os.path.join(td, f'file{i}') for i in range(2)]
    with open(f_names[0], 'w') as fh:
        fh.write('this is the foo file')
    with open(f_names[1], 'w') as fh:
        fh.write(process_file(f_names[0]))
```